# How can I run matched string as a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a *very* basic templating system and struggling.

Take this:

```
some useless text here but i want to replace %% this %% with the variable: object.this
```

This seems like it'd be easy, but I can't figure it out. Here's my code:

```
function loadTemplate(element, object) {
    var regex = /%% (.*) %%/;
    return $(element).html().replace(regex, eval("object.$1"));
}
```

I've tried a few different things. Currently the eval returns `undefined`. When I try `eval("$1")`, it gives me an uncaught reference error and tells me that `$1` isn't defined.

Comment: You don't need `eval` as `replace` takes a callback function; do your logic there.

Comment: @elclanrs, I'm using `eval` to just run the string as a variable.

Comment: See my answer, you don't need it. You can use bracket notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `eval` as `replace` takes a callback function; do your logic there. The first parameter is the matched substring, the second one is the first capturing group match. Using bracket notation you can access the object's key dynamically with a string:

```
.replace(regex, function(_, a) {
  return object[a];
});
```

Comment: Perhaps I really really suck, but it still returns 'undefined', though I know that it's matching the right thing. Also, would `.replace(regex, object["$1"]` be the same as your answer?

Comment: It's not the same. The replacement tokens are passed in a string to the `replace` method. That doesn't mean that you can use them in any string. The second parameter of `replace` is either a string or a function. `object["$1"]` will literally look up the key `$1` in `object`, not what you need here.

Comment: okay that makes sense. also ignore my previous comment regarding it returning undefined. this is working perfectly. thank you! -- edit: still gotta wait 2 minutes to accept your answer